# Add TODO to an external org file.

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to write some prose. I have emacs configured well for all of the writing, but there is one issue I am having trouble resolving.

As I write I may have an idea or I may want to make a note to myself to review during the editing process. Maybe I want to change a character name or I want to research an idea in more detail. I don't want to get out of the flow of writing so I just want to create a quick TODO in a different org file with a link to the line/word in my prose where I need to make the edit.

I've figured out how to create the link but I cannot get it to match to a TODO item. Any suggestions for this frustrated writer? Ideally I would like to create a capture template so I can add the note quickly and just keep writing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the org-capture module already has a concept for that:
http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html
When you place

```
%a
```

In your capture template, it will create a link to the to the location from where you called the capture command.

I assume the given example is exactly what you want:

```
     (setq org-capture-templates
  '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

I hope, this helps :)

Comment: Yes, that resolved it nicely. I missed that when I was looking for a fix. Thank you.